# Restrictions in overloading operator new function

Tags: c++

The operator new function can be overloaded but it requires the first argument to be a unsigned int i.e. an overloaded function should also take an unsigned int as its first argument.

```
// Okay since the first argument is unsigned int
void * operator new(size_t size, Arena& arena, std::string msg)
// Not okay. since the first argument is not an unsigned int
void * operator new(Arena& arena, std::string msg)
```

How is this enforced? can we enforce similar restrictions for user defined functions?

Answer (score 0):

With operator overloading in C++, operator signature is determined by the C++ standard. The standard goes further and mentions a few opeartors where overloading is not allowed(`?:`, `::` etc).

I'm not a *language lawyer* to pull out stuff from C++ standards, but apperently as described in [cpp-reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) there are accepted pre-defined function signatures for `new operator` as with any other operator. With the function signature that is shown in your example, it seems that user defined placement allocation functions are defined. According to [cpp-reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) the first argument should always be of `size_t` type for that particular operator new overload.

P.S. It is `operator new` not `operator new function`.

Comment: It is defined as a function. Check http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/

Comment: @SureshKumar We need to write a function to overload an operator - which is correct. My comment is that we don't call it `opearator new function` in the same manner we call `operator overloading` instead of `operator function overloading`. It's just the usage of the term, nothing more than that.